# how to test a microservice which is getting data from a broker

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit

I have a microservice which gets data from azure bus and store it in the DB,im not using any controller to be hit from outside so,i cant use

```
  var response = await _client.GetAsync("/");
```

any idea how should i test such a scenario?

Comment: As you said that you have no controller so that it can't be hit from outside, then if you can create a controller or main method for the test?

Comment: @TinyWangis that a right way?i think you should not create integration test for a single microservice,but you are saying in this case he has to create a controller to test?